# Mongoose and new Schema: returns "ReferenceError: Schema is not defined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a new sample application, where I try to connect to a MongoDB database through Mongoose.

I create a new schema in my `service.js` file, but I get the following error when I run `nodemon app.js`: `"ReferenceError: Schema is not defined"`

**App.js code:**

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var serials = require('./service');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var port = 4000;
app.listen(port);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/serialnumbers')

app.get('/api/serials',function(req,res){
    serials.getSerial(req, res, function(err, data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

**Service.js code:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var serialSchema = new Schema({
    serial: {type: String},
    game: {type: String},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});
mongoose.model('serials', serialSchema);

exports.getSerial = function(req,res,cb) {
    mongoose.model('serials').find(function(err,data) {
        cb(err,data);
    });
};
```

I saw an answer here on StackOverflow that referenced it could be the version of Mongoose. But `npm list` gives me this:

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Exactly, in your `Service.js`, what is `Schema`? You don't have an object named `Schema`.

```
...
var serialSchema = new Schema({
                       ^^^^^^
```

change it to `mongoose.Schema` then it will be fine.

Comment: Or add `var Schema = mongoose.Schema;`  below `var mongoose = reguire('mongoose');`

Answer (score 9):

Define `Schema` like this on your second line:

```js
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
```

Comment: Sorry, this answer doesn't add anything new to the existing one.

Comment: This makes a bit more sense if you are using objects like 'Schema.Types.Mixed' inside the Schema definitions.

Bit easier to look at than 'mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed', but maybe a bit less explicit.

Answer (score 5):

This can be occurred due to several reasons. first one is that you might forgotten to import Schema.You can fix that as follows.

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const serialSchema = new Schema({
   serial: {type: String},
   game: {type: String},
   date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});
```

Sometimes you have forgotten to import your newly created model.This type of errors can be solve by importing created model to your working file.

```
const serialModel = mongoose.model('serials', serialSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;
```

From: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was referencing a schema inside of another schema and had to replace type: Schema.Types.ObjectId with mongoose.Types.ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

In you case call as `mongoose.Schema` as you did not defined it as

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
then
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

Answer (score -1):

Between your
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
and
var serialSchema = new Schema({
Add
Const Schema= mongoose.Schema

That defines the schema and solves the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).