# Module unrecognised in Angular while using Node & Mongo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

Working on a primitive enough MEAN-stack project.
When I run the application, the data-binding fails as the module which makes the association between my View and Backend(makes the http connection to my DB) never gets instantiated, and goes unrecognised.

Following error message appears in the console

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module moviesApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'moviesApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Error message is fairly understandable. I seem to have incorrectly(or not at all) created the link between the view "MoviesList.html" and the file containing the module I mentioned above (moviesApp), in the file "Movies.js".

Movies.js makes use of a factory. I've checked the general syntax(can't see how incorrect code inside the actual factory would cause the module to go unrecognised). Having written a basic factory before on jsfiddle, i'm confident that the syntax should be fine. https://jsfiddle.net/Sheepy99/4wmd3zd0/ (granted I chained the factory in that example, but it's the same general premise)

Before I post the rest of my code, it's based off of the example contained here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/nodejs/1032/nodejs-apps-in-visual-studio-mean-stack 
Some of my code is different due to differing versions, and some bits being deprecated since the author published the article(also wondering why he consistently uses double double-quotes).

Any ambiguity or loose ends, ask away.

MoviesList.html

```
<html>
<!--<meta charset="UTF-8">-->
<title>Node-Express Movie List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/site.css">-->
 
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="/scripts/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/movies.js"></script>-->

    <script src="../public/scripts/movies.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/scripts/controller.js"></script>    
</head>


<body>    
    <div class="container">
        <!--<div class="text-center" ng-app="moviesApp" ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">-->
        <div class="text-center" ng-app="moviesApp" ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">
            <h1>Node-Express Movie List</h1>
            <div class="col-md-12" control-group="">
                <input type="text" style="width: 200px;" ng-model="newMovieText">
                <button id="btnAddTodo" class="btn" style="margin: 2px;" ng-click="addMovie()" ng-disabled="newMovieText">Add Movie</button>
            </div>
 
            <div class="col-md-5" sticky-note="">
                <h3 class="text-center">Released Movies</h3>
                <!--<div class="col-md-5" rowmargin="" todoitem="" ng-repeat="movie" in="" movies="" |="" filter:{released:true}"="">-->
                <div class="col-md-5" rowmargin="" todoitem="" ng-repeat="movie" in="" movies="" filter:{released:true}>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="movie.watched" ng-change="movieWatched(movie)">
                      
                        <span ng-class="{watchedMovie: movie.watched}">{{movie.name}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 
            <div class="col-md-5" sticky-note="">
                <h3 class="text-center">Coming Up...</h3>
                <div class="col-md-5" rowmargin="" todoitem="" ng-repeat="movie" in="" movies="" filter:{released:false}>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        {{movie.name}}
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <input type="button" value="Released!" class="btn btn-success" btn-link="" released-button="" ng-click="movieReleased(movie)" style="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

movies.js

```
var app = angular.module('moviesApp', []);
 
app.factory('moviesCRUD', function ($http, $q) {
    function getAllMovies() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
 
        $http.get('/api/movies').then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result.data);
        }, function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
 
        return deferred.promise;
    }
 
    function addMovie(newMovie) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
 
        $http.post('/api/movies', newMovie).then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result.data.movie);
        }, function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
 
        return deferred.promise;
    }
 
    function modifyMovie(updatedMovie) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
 
        $http.put('/api/movies/' + updatedMovie._id, updatedMovie).then(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }, function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });
 
        return deferred.promise;
    }
 
    return {
        getAllMovies: getAllMovies,
        addMovie: addMovie,
        modifyMovie: modifyMovie
    };
});
```

mongoOperations.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908405/mongoose-and-new-schema-returns-referenceerror-schema-is-not-defined 
//link recommends use of what's on line 2 as a solution

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; //not using promises, this line removes a default setting and also gets rid of a warning about promises
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/moviesDb');
var db = mongoose.connection;

//var movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({  *I shouldn't need this because i've declared "require('mongoose')"
var movieSchema = new Schema({
name: String, //doesn't like if I have spaces on each new line, before the use of characters
released: Boolean,
watched: Boolean
});
var MovieModel = mongoose.model('movie', movieSchema);

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, "connection error"));
db.once('open', function () {
    //console.log("moviesDb is open...");     
    MovieModel.find().exec(function (error, results) {
        if (results.length === 0) {
            MovieModel.create({ name: "The Amazing Spider-Man 2", released: true, watched: false });
            MovieModel.create({ name: "The Other Woman", released: true, watched: true });
            MovieModel.create({ name: "Shaadi ke Side Effects", released: false, watched: false });
            MovieModel.create({ name: "Walk of Shame", released: true, watched: false });
            MovieModel.create({ name: "Lucky Kabootar", released: false, watched: false });
        }
    });
});

exports.fetch = function (request, response) {
    MovieModel.find().exec(function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
             response.send(500, { error: err });
        }
        else {
            response.send(res);
        }
    });
};
exports.add = function (request, response) {
    var newMovie = { name: request.body.name, released: false, watched: false };
    MovieModel.create(newMovie, function (addError, addedMovie) {
        if (addError) {
            response.send(500, { error: addError });
        }
        else {
            response.send({ success: true, movie: addedMovie });
        }
    });
};
exports.modify = function (request, response) {
    var movieId = request.params.movieId;
    MovieModel.update({ _id: movieId }, { released: request.body.released, watched: request.body.watched }, { multi: false },
        function (error, rowsAffected) {
        if (error) {
            response.send(500, { error: error });
        }
        else if (rowsAffected == 0) {
            response.send(500, { error: "No rows affected" });
        }
        else {
            response.send(200);
        }
    }
);
};
```

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require("path");
 
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
 
var app = express();
//app.use(bodyParser()); //getting deprecated warning in shell when using this specific line
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//app.use(bodyParser.json()); used in stackoverflow solution, can see potential benefit, but isn't helping
var mongoOps = require('./server/MongoOperations.js');
 
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    //response.sendfile("views/MoviesList.html");
    //response.sendFile("views/MoviesList.html");
    response.sendFile("views/MoviesList.html", { "root": __dirname });
});

app.get('/api/list', function (request, response) {
    response.send([{ id: 1, name: "charlie" }, { "id": 2, "name": "ward" }]);
        //'Hello World!');
});

app.get('/api/movies', mongoOps.fetch);
 
app.post('/api/movies', mongoOps.add);
 
app.put('/api/movies/:movieId', mongoOps.modify);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.listen(port);
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope, moviesCRUD) {
    $scope.released = { released: true };
    $scope.notReleased = { released: false };
     
    function init() {
        moviesCRUD.getAllMovies().then(function (movies) {
            $scope.movies = movies;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });        
    }
 
    $scope.movieReleased = function (movie) {
 
        moviesCRUD.modifyMovie({ _id: movie._id, name: movie.name, released: true, watched: movie.watched })
                  .then(function (result) {
                      if (result.status === 200) {
                          movie.released = true;
                      }
                  }, function (error) {
                      console.log(error);
                  });        
    };
 
    $scope.movieWatched = function (movie) {
        moviesCRUD.modifyMovie(movie)
                  .then(function (result) {
                      if (result.status === 200) {
                          console.log("Movie updated");
                      }
                  }, function (error) {
                      movie.watched = !movie.watched;
                  });        
    };
 
    $scope.addMovie = function () {
        moviesCRUD.addMovie({ name: $scope.newMovieText }).then(function (newMovie) {
            $scope.movies.push(newMovie);
            $scope.newMovieText = "";
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });        
    };
 
    init();
});
```

Also, much of my html is being rendered as question marks inside diamonds. This has me absolutely puzzled. Just thought i'd put that out there.

As a noobie, any brief general suggestions would be welcomed, as in adjustments to my code for readability, or approach.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes to your code to get Angular to "compile" it, but I didn't have the code for the controller so I could not finish setting it up. But if you look at this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/pZGcyLsQNdocEHPAEWF2?p=preview), you can see my changes.

```
<html ng-app="moviesApp">

  <head>
    <!--<meta charset="UTF-8">-->
    <title>Node-Express Movie List</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.1" data-semver="1.6.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/site.css">-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="/scripts/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/movies.js"></script>-->
    <script src="movies.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="../public/scripts/controller.js"></script>-->
  </head>
```

You had issues with the placement of the HEAD in the HTML, plus you bootstrapped the application in the first DIV, which I guess it could work, but it is very non-standard. You start your application in a Plunk or Codepen to make it easier on yourself.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

Because I have the following line near the bottom of server.js, my directory automatically starts of public, when specifying directives for external modules(in this case controller.js and movies.js.
Therefore, my directives were incorrect. 
As for the strange diamonds I had mentioned at the bottom of my question, it was due to my files being automatically being saved as ASCII when I created them, when they should've been UTF-8.

An annoying and pedantic problem, but i'm sure someone will eventually find some help from this.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```