# type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, returns “ReferenceError: Schema is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongoose, database-design

I'm designing a database schema, where referencing to userschema, an error occurred, when I wrote the code below:

```
postedBy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },

type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ^
ReferenceError: Schema is not defined
```

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908405/mongoose-and-new-schema-returns-referenceerror-schema-is-not-defined

Answer (score 1):

You have to add:

`mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`

instead of:

`Schema.Types.ObjectId`.

Else add:

`const Schema = require('mongoose').Schema`.